How to use Abort and Throw?
I was wondering if there is a way to break the following triple loop once condition01 is satisfied
Do[Do[Do[
    Which[BLA BLA BLA,  
     list01[[k]] = Append[list01[[k]], list[[i]]]
                             ];   
       If[condition01, Break[]] , {k, 1, 
     SomeNumber}], {j, 1, h}], {i, 1, h}];

I know that Break will only break out of the immediately enclosing loop.
Somebody told me in another forume to use Abort or Throw (he told me too that with Throw I'd also typically wrap the whole thing in Catch: "I have no idea what that means").
Could somebody show me how to use this Abort and Throw functions.
Thanks in advance

You shouldn't use Abort here. Abort is used for situations where something is seriously going wrong and you need to bail out of the whole evaluation right away. It's not meant for breaking out of a loop or something like that.
To use Throw + Catch:
Catch[
  Do[Do[Do[
     Which[BLA BLA BLA, 
      list01[[k]] = Append[list01[[k]], list[[i]]]];
     If[condition01, Throw[list01, "myTag"]], {k, 1, SomeNumber}], {j,
      1, h}], {i, 1, h}],
  "myTag"
  ];

The "myTag" string can be anything; it just tells WL which Throw should go to which Catch. See the documentation for more details.
